# Java method instantiation

Tags: java

I have a question regarding Java method instantiation. Which is :

What is the difference between :

```
new className().methodName();
```

and

```
className reference = new className();
reference.methodName()
```

because in the following code :

```
 public doc() {
    initComponents();
    //dData();
}

public void dData(){
    try{
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        String sql = "SELECT doctorBusiness.id, doctorBusiness.doctorname, doctorBusiness.patientName, doctorBusiness.xComm, doctorBusiness.labComm, doctorBusiness.ecgComm, doctorBusiness.spcComm, doctorBusiness.dateofreport, doctorBusiness.totalEarnt FROM doctorBusiness";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://test.accdb");
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        jXTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in fetching data\n"+e);
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new doc().setVisible(true);
            new doc().dData(); // <-------- Facing problem here
        }
    });
}
```

Whether I do `new doc().dData();` or properly instantiate the reference with
 `doc d = new doc();
 d.dData();`, 

it does not invoke the method.

Whereas calling inside the constructor always invokes the method, like this :

```
public doc() {
    initComponents();
    dData();
}
```

Comment: In your `Runnable`, your two `doc` instances are different from one another!

Comment: `doc` is the `className` which is a frame too.

Comment: @mustangDC you currently have 2 frames but only first one is visible

Comment: @FastSnail : den how do I properly instantiate the method inside the `Runnable` ?

Comment: @fge : Yes they are, but here I just need to properly instantiate the method `dData()` inside the `Runnable`

Comment: @mustangDC read both following answers .when you need to call more than one method of a object you have to assign it and then call .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply it makes two instances of doc

```
new doc().setVisible(true);
new doc().dData();
```

The code below it creates a single instance and using it multiple times

```
doc d=new doc();
d.setVisible(true);
d.dData();
```

create an instance and call it's methods in proper order OR you can call other method in the end of the first method. it depends on your requirements. If you have case where you need to run first method only. Then second approach will be worst.

Comment: @mustangDC `only instantiates the frame but not the dData()` nope only objects can instantiates .`dData()` is a method like `setVisible(true)` .you should call both method in a single instance every time you call `new doc()` will create new class in this case a frame .

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was just confused with the basic stuff. Cheers .

Comment: @Exbury : Just another clarification : does `new doc()` creates a new class every time we call like this? Or just a onetime reference to the `class`. I am just confused because we have variable answers here. Thanks

Comment: new doc() will create a new instance every time when you call like this. search about new operator you will find how JVM creates and handles objects.

Comment: Fine, but my previous comment was just because of your statement **`new doc()` will create new class in this case a frame**. But thanks anyways for the help :)

Comment: that is not my statement .look at the author

Comment: :), I completely agree @Exbury. But what should we deduce from the author's statement a `class` or an `instance`. That is the matter of concern. Anyways

Comment: it is the instance not class. That is a mistake

Answer (score 3):

> new className().methodName();

It creates a new object and invokes it's `methodName` and floats in Java Heap. You can no longer use this same object as have not captured it in any Reference.

> className reference = new className();
>   reference.methodName()

This time your object's reference is captured into `reference` variable, this same object can be used any number of time you want by using `reference`.

```
...
public static void main(String args[]) {

java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        new doc().setVisible(true);
        new doc().dData(); // <-------- Facing problem here
    }
});
```

}

Here, `setVisible` is called on different object & `dData` is called on another name-less object, Both of these method invocation are on different objects.

Instead, you should use the same object for

```
...
public static void main(String args[]) {

java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        doc obj = new doc();
        obj.setVisible(true);
        obj.dData(); // <-------- This would work fine
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, concepts are getting clearer now

Comment: Just a clearification :- `new className().methodName();`, does not it create a new `Class` every time I do this.?

Comment: Nope, `new className()` creates an instance of the `className` class.

Comment: I knew that but as @Exbury said **every time you call `new doc()` will create new class in this case a frame**, i am just a bit confused

Comment: Class is nothing but a prototype. `new doc()` only creates a new instance not a class, i think that 'd be a typo by @Fast Snail